# How to subclass Observable in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

I know you should avoid that at all costs, but what if I have a valid use case for a subclassed Observable in RxJava? Is it possible? How could I do it?

In this specific case, I have a "repository" class which currently returns Requests:

```
class Request<T> {
    public abstract Object key();
    public abstract Observable<T> asObservable();

    [...]

    public Request<T> transform(Func1<Request<T>, Observable<T>> transformation) {
        Request<T> self = this;
        return new Request<T>() {
             @Override public Object key() { return self.key; }
             @Override public Observable<T> asObservable() { return transformation.call(self); }
        }
    }
}
```

I then use the transform method to modify the response observable (asObservable) in a context where I need the request key (like caching):

```
 service.getItemList() // <- returns a Request<List<Item>>
     .transform(r -> r.asObservable()
             // The activity is the current Activity in Android
             .compose(Operators.ensureThereIsAnAccount(activity))
             // The cache comes last because we don't need auth for cached responses
             .compose(cache.cacheTransformation(r.key())))
     .asObservable()
     [...  your common RxJava code ...]
```

Now, it would be pretty convenient if my Request class was an Observable subclass, since I could then eliminate all the .asObservable() calls and clients wouldn't even need to know about my Request class.

Comment: If you're sure you really want to make things that messy: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables but it sure seems like this code above is mixing up concerns.

Comment: I can't find any reference on *subclassing* Observables there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Observable is probably not intended to be subclassed. Remember _Effective Java_ Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance. Why do you think subclassing is correct here?

Comment: But there's ConnectableObservable in RxJava.

Comment: To quote Item 16's intro: "Inheritance is a powerful way to achieve code reuse, but it is not always the best tool for the job. Used inappropriately, it leads to fragile software. It is safe to use inheritance within a package, where the subclass and the superclass implementations are under the control of the same programmers. It is also safe to use inheritance when extending classes specifically designed and documented for extension (Item 17). Inheriting from ordinary concrete classes across package boundaries, however, is dangerous."

Comment: So again I ask: why should your `Request` class _be_ an `Observable`? Just to avoid the `.transform(r::asObservable)`?

Comment: Because why not, man? I ask you, why shouldn't it be?

Comment: Did you read _Effective Java_ Item 16?

Comment: Nope. But I have an answer for you now: It should *be* an Observable because every single time I use my Request class, I end up calling *asObservable()* in the end. That is why it should be an Observable. Because it *is* an Observable. Even futher than that. I always start and end calling *asObservable* whenever I use my Request class. I could remove that *r.key()* by encapsulating that inside my *Request.transform* method, so the transform function wouldn't even know about my Request existance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72498/discussion-between-dirleyrls-and-matt-ball).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible to subclass Observable (we do this for `Subject`s and `ConnectableObservable`s), but it requires extra consideration, because you need to pass in an `OnSubscribe` callback to handle your incoming `Subscriber`s. It is not clear for me what your Request should do in case someone subscribes to it, so I'll give you two examples of extending an Observable:

### Observable without shared mutable state

If you don't have mutable state to be shared between subscribers, you can just extend Observable and pass in your action to to `super`

```java
public final class MyObservable extends Observable<Long> {
    public MyObservable() {
        super(new OnSubscribe<Long>() {
            @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Long> child) {
                child.onNext(System.currentTimeMillis());
                child.onCompleted();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Observable with shared mutable state

This one is usually trickier because you need to access a shared state from both the `OnSubscribe` method and your Observable's methods, but Java won't let you touch instance fields from the `OnSubscribe` inner class before `super` has completed. The solution is to factor out such a shared state and the `OnSubscribe` from the constructor and use a static factory method to set up both:

```java
public final class MySharedObservable extends Observable<Long> {
    public static MySharedObservable create() {
        final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
        OnSubscribe<Long> onSubscribe = new OnSubscribe<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Long> t1) {
                t1.onNext(counter.incrementAndGet());
                t1.onCompleted();
            }
        };
        return new MySharedObservable(onSubscribe, counter);
    }
    private AtomicLong counter;

    private MySharedObservable(OnSubscribe<Long> onSubscribe, AtomicLong counter) {
        super(onSubscribe);
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public long getCounter() {
        return counter.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but how do I cancel said subscription? The onSubscribe returns void, and there's no obvious way to cancel (lets say your counter does something asynchronous like start a thread or issue a network request... how does one stop the external thing?)

Comment: Oops, nevermind. subscriber has a .isUnsubscribed() on it which you can call. RxJava is completely bonkers coming from a C# Rx background